# ontaskchanged Error occured

Tags: workflow, tasks, workflow-activity

I'm trying to create a simple workflow containing a while in which you can find : createtaskwithcontenttypes 
while
    Ontaskchanged
completetask

When I try to launch the workflow by adding a new item to my associate list, I find myself with a "Error occured". So I tried to debug a little and found out that the error was on the ontaskchanged event receiver. But the only thing it does is leaving the workflow. I have no error message or whatever.

So I've looked upon the internet, and found out some similar problem. But I guess I didn't find mine, or I didn't understand what it was about !

Here is my create task method :

```
private void createTaskWithContentType1_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskProperties = new SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
    TaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
    TaskProperties.Title = Title;
    TaskProperties.Description = DescriptionName;
    TaskProperties.DueDate = DueDate;
    TaskProperties.AssignedTo = this.Approver;
    TaskProperties.PercentComplete = 0;
    TaskProperties.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Here is my while code condition :

```
private void WaitResponse_Invoke(object sender, ConditionalEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = !isFinished;
}
```

Here is the invoked method of my ontaskchanged event receiver (basically does nothing) :

```
private void WaitApproval_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
{           
}
```

Here are the after and before propertie :
public static DependencyProperty WaitApproval_AfterPropertiesProperty =

```
DependencyProperty.Register("WaitApproval_AfterProperties", typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties), typeof(ActivityLibrary.EtapeOuiNon));

    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
    [CategoryAttribute("Misc")]
    public Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties WaitApproval_AfterProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties)(base.GetValue(ActivityLibrary.EtapeOuiNon.WaitApproval_AfterPropertiesProperty)));
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(ActivityLibrary.EtapeOuiNon.WaitApproval_AfterPropertiesProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty WaitApproval_BeforePropertiesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WaitApproval_BeforeProperties", typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties), typeof(ActivityLibrary.EtapeOuiNon));

    [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
    [CategoryAttribute("Misc")]
    public Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties  WaitApproval_BeforeProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties)(base.GetValue(ActivityLibrary.EtapeOuiNon.WaitApproval_BeforePropertiesProperty)));
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(ActivityLibrary.EtapeOuiNon.WaitApproval_BeforePropertiesProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

For information the correlation token is the same everywhere. Also all of this part of my workflow are in a separate activity.

So if someone has an idea of what it could be ! 
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem ! 
When the ontaskchanged event is accessed, the workflow is trying to serialize itself, so that it can be stock while waiting for the event to be triggered !

The problem is that in my workflow i was using personalize object which were not serialazible as public variable :

```
public sealed partial class Workflow1 : SequentialWorkflowActivity
{
    public Workflow1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public List<DefEtape> ListeEtapes = new List<DefEtape>();
    public DefEtape etapeEnCours = new DefEtape();
```

To overcome this proble I've just added  : [Serializable] to my classes so that it became :

```
namespace CSPIMMOHelper
{
    [Serializable]
    public class DefEtape
    {
```

I hope this will help some people

Comment: Hi Thomas, if you have answered your own question - don't forget to mark it as answered :-)

Comment: Yep, just couldn't do it before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you this was the solution to my problem! i had an SPListItem in my Class that is unserializable, as a bug with it in general.

The issue can be found in the ULS logs